# Connecting API with laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, api, token

I need to connect to an API with my Laravel 5.1 project so I write function to test:

```
public function testDng() {

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false ]);
try {
    $res = $client->post('https://api.example.com/api/authenticate', [

    'form_params' => [
        'email' => 'john@example.com',
        'password' => 'asdasd'
]
            ]);
return $res;
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $result =  json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    return response()->json(['data' => $result]);

    }

}
```

The result of this function is:

```
{"data":null}
```

but when I try this API in Postman app everything is fine and I get token:

[image]

So something is wrong with my function ... What caused the problem and why I cant get token?

Comment: It looks like you got a client exception since your run in the catch block. You sending 10 headers in Postman but none with Guzzle. Maybe there is one header which is missing.

Comment: Voila, you have your real error. If it works with postman and Laravel gives you a 404, I would assume, that you are calling the wrong URI with Laravel.

Comment: but no... the same URL is at Postman and the same URL is at Laravel function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error it says https://api.dineandgift.com/api/authenticate but in the Postman screenshots the URL (in the hidden tabs) starts with https://app.di[...]